# How to save file using ng-file-upload in ASP .NET Web API 2 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ng-file-upload

i try save file to server, i'm using the **`ng-file-upload`** directive, i added the next *html - code*:

```
<button class="button" ngf-select ng-model="fileCover" name="fileCover" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
 ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100">Select</button>

 <button type="submit" ng-click="submitUpload(fileCover)">submit</button>
```

and my *angularjs-code*:

```
 $scope.submitUpload = function (fileCover) {
    console.log(fileCover);
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/upload',
        data: { file: fileCover }
    });

};
```

And i have a empty controller:

```
  [Route("upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Upload ( )
    {

    }
```

Tell me please, how i can save files at server side ?Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution using an older version of ng-file-upload (angular-file-upload), and my WebApi method that received the file looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload() {
    try {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) {
            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // On upload, files are given a generic name like "BodyPart_26d6abe1-3ae1-416a-9429-b35f15e6e5d5"
        // so this is how you can get the original file name
        var originalFileName = GetDeserializedFileName(result.FileData.First());

        // uploadedFileInfo object will give you some additional stuff like file length,
        // creation time, directory name, a few filesystem methods etc..
        var uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FileData.First().LocalFileName);

        // Create full path for where to move the uploaded file
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(uploadedFileInfo.DirectoryName, originalFileName);

        // If the file in the full path exists, delete it first otherwise FileInfo.MoveTo() will throw exception
        if (File.Exists(targetFile)) 
            File.Delete(targetFile);
        }

        // Move the uploaded file to the target folder
        uploadedFileInfo.MoveTo(targetFile);

        // targetFile now contains the uploaded file

        // Through the request response you can return an object to the Angular controller
        // You will be able to access this in the .success callback through its data attribute
        // If you want to send something to the .error callback, use the HttpStatusCode.BadRequest instead
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new ObjectContent(ex.GetType(), ex, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()) };
    }
}

private MultipartFormDataStreamProvider GetMultipartProvider() {
    var uploadFolder = @"C:\Temp"

    if (Directory.Exists(uploadFolder) == false) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

    return new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadFolder);
}

private string GetDeserializedFileName(MultipartFileData fileData) {
    var fileName = GetFileName(fileData);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileName).ToString();
}

private string GetFileName(MultipartFileData fileData) {
    return fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
}
```

Hopefully the server side functionality hasn't changed much in the versions between what I'm using and the one you are using.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your answer it works. How i can save [link to screenshot](http://prntscr.com/by1ui9)  some text field together with file ?